# Обработчик события onkeypress для тега ins

Tags: javascript, html

Работаю с тегом , на который мне нужно повесить два обработчика событий: `onpaste` и `onkeypress`. 
Для наглядности:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ins")[0].onkeypress = function(e) {inputHandler(e)};
document.getElementsByTagName("ins")[0].onpaste = function(e) {pasteHandler(e)};

function inputHandler(e){
  alert("Keypress");
}

function pasteHandler(e){
  alert("Paste");
}
```

`onkeypress` отрабатывает корректно, но `onkeypress` не работает совсем, я нашла мануал, по которому все должно работать с тегом ins, может он устарел?
Если да, то получается, что невозможно повесить обработчик `onkeypress` на `<ins>`?
Ссылка на код: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zMoOWj?editors=1010

Ссылка на мануал: http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onkeypress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Событие `onkeypress` не срабатывает из за того что элемент `ins` не получает фокус при вводе текста. 
Варианты решений:
1) Добавить для `<ins>, tabindex="0"`

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("ins")[0].onkeypress = function(e) {inputHandler(e)};
document.getElementsByTagName("ins")[0].onpaste = function(e) {pasteHandler(e)};

function inputHandler(e){
  alert("Keypress");
}

function pasteHandler(e){
  alert("Paste");
}
```

```html
<div id="mainBlock" contenteditable="true">
        AAAAAA<br>
        <ins tabindex="0"> 1текст 2текст 1________1    3текст 4текст</ins><br>
        AAAA<br>
    </div>
```

2) сделать `<div id="mainBlock" contenteditable="false">"`, а `<ins contenteditable="true"></ins>`

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("ins")[0].onkeypress = function(e) {inputHandler(e)};
document.getElementsByTagName("ins")[0].onpaste = function(e) {pasteHandler(e)};
function inputHandler(e){
    alert("Keypress");
}

function pasteHandler(e){
  alert("Paste");
}
```

```html
<div id="mainBlock" contenteditable="false">
        AAAAAA<br>
        <ins contenteditable="true"> 1текст 2текст 1________1    3текст 4текст</ins><br>
        AAAA<br>
    </div>
```

3) обернуть `<ins>` со свойстов `contenteditable="true"` в `<div>` со свойстов contenteditable="flase"

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("ins")[0].onkeypress = function(e) {inputHandler(e)};
document.getElementsByTagName("ins")[0].onpaste = function(e) {pasteHandler(e)};
function inputHandler(e){
    alert("Keypress");
}

function pasteHandler(e){
  alert("Paste");
}
```

```html
<div id="mainBlock" contenteditable="true">
        AAAAAA<br>
  <div contenteditable="false">
        <ins contenteditable="true"> 1текст 2текст 1________1    3текст 4текст</ins><br>
    </div>
        AAAA<br>
    </div>
```